# How to send sms in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

Look at my  codes

web.php

```
Route::get('/mobileServices',['as' => 'mobileServices'], function (){
    Alert::message('Welcome back!');
});
```

blade.php

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="{{ route('mobileServices') }}">Mobile Services</a> </td>
</tr>
```

I tried but I et this error.

> Function () does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try naming your route like this...

```
Route::get('/mobileServices', function (){
    Alert::message('Welcome back!');
})->name('mobileServices');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes